# Possible to group rows by number range?

Tags: grouping, tabulator

With tabulator, I am able to group my data by the values in a specific column.

In my case, I have data like this:

```
ID: 0
number: 1
description: "first transponder"
assigned_to: "driver three"


ID: 1
number: 2
description: "second transponder"
assigned_to: "driver four"


ID: 2
number: 3
description: "third transponder"
assigned_to: "driver five"
```

And the list goes on up to number 9999.

Of course it is totally senseless to display 9999 rows in hundreds of pages. But  at the end of the day, I still need to be able to select one specific row for editing.

So my thought is to group the data by the number field in ranges of 50 or so (so from 1 to 50, 51 to 100, 101 to 150 and so on).

According to the documentation, I see no possibility to do so.
Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

One option may be to calculate the number of pages you would have, based on the page size you need, and assign each row a group name based on which page range they fall under. Then have tabulator group by these ranges.  Here is a simplified example with 5 entries and page size of 2:

```js
// Paginate data
let pageSize = 2
let pages = data.length < pageSize ? 1 : Math.ceil(data.length / pageSize)

let groups = []
let index = 1

for (i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
  let to = index + pageSize - 1
  groups.push([index, to > data.length ? data.length : to])
  index += pageSize
}

// Tabulator
let table = new Tabulator("#table", {
  data: data,
  autoColumns: true,
  groupBy: (data) => {
    // Depending on which page group the number is in, assign it to the group
    for (i of groups) {
      if (data.number >= i[0] && data.number <= i[1]) {
        return i[0] + ' to ' + i[1]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.4.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.4.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="table"></div>
<script>
  const data = [{
    ID: 0,
    number: 1,
    description: "first transponder",
    assigned_to: "driver three"
  }, {
    ID: 1,
    number: 2,
    description: "second transponder",
    assigned_to: "driver four"
  }, {

    ID: 2,
    number: 3,
    description: "third transponder",
    assigned_to: "driver five"
  }, {
    ID: 3,
    number: 4,
    description: "fourth transponder",
    assigned_to: "driver four"
  }, {
    ID: 4,
    number: 5,
    description: "fifth transponder",
    assigned_to: "driver five"
  }]
</script>
```